# Microsoft OLAP based DW Solution

Tags: data-warehouse, olap, olap-cube

We are trying to build a data warehouse prototype and we are architecting in the below way

```
Source - > Staging DW (via ETL) -> Prod DW (via ETL) -> OLAP Cube (SSAS) -> BI Tool
```

In the past when I have worked on other warehouses, the BI tool usually sits both on the DW and the cube but in this case we are trying to see if we can do all the querying and reporting building via the cube (especially because the cube technology has come a long way and rebuilding a cube is not costly as it used to be and disk is cheeper than what it used to be). The one clear advantage I see is that the BI tool will have much better query times as it's going to be on the cube. However, I am not sure if we are missing anything by giving away by not exposing the database layer on the BI tool.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, It depends on the business and reporting needs. In a very matured organization the data is always exposed via cubes using BI tools.

Many of us use CUBE reports for the analytical dashboards( drill down, drill-thru etc)  and it will be based on large data-set.It's  pre-calculated and it's stale.

Exposing PROD DW/ STG DW on BI Tool will help us to  generate near real time reports and adhoc reports for business users based on some reporting criteria .

Regards
SB